# how to write concat operation for a query string with single quote and percentage

Tags: excel

select * from items  where entry_id in(select entry_id from entry where number like '56780357906392%')

how to write concat operation for above string. Below formula not working

="select * from items  where entry_id in(select entry_id from entry where number like "&A1 '%')

Comment: Excel doesn't support SQL statement. You need vba macro.

Comment: in excel one row I have employee id,I need to concatenate this sql query to all the numbers that exists in A column

Comment: `.....Like '"&A1&"%'"` maybe?

Comment: @JvdV probably `...like "&A1&"%')"`

Comment: ="select * from items   where entry_id in(select entry_id from entry where number like "&A1  &"%')"
 extra quote is coming before %
 select * from items  where entry_id in(select entry_id from entry where number like '9780357906392'%')